# Non-isomorphic countable linear orders which embed into each other

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Def: $(A,<) \hookrightarrow (B,\lhd)$ if $\exists f:A \to B$ such that $\forall a,b \in A[a<b \implies f(a) \lhd f(b)]$.

May I seek your advice on how to construct two infinite, countable linear orders $(A,<)$ and $ (B,\lhd)$ such that $(A,<) \hookrightarrow (B,\lhd)$ and $(B,\lhd) \hookrightarrow (A,<)$, but $(A,<)$ and $(B,\lhd)$ are not isomorphic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

Note that $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$; but not to $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$. Both with the standard order.

Comment: Thanks. May I know how you prove there is no surjective function from $ \mathbb {Q} \cap [0,1]$ onto $\mathbb {Q}$ ?

Comment: There is a surjective function but it cannot be an isomirphism because of the endpoints.

Comment: Ok. It is not difficult to see that $(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1], <)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, <),$ where $<$ is the standard ordering of rationals. But, is it possible to show $(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1], \rhd)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q, \lhd)$, where $\lhd, \rhd$ are not the standard orderings?

Comment: @Alexy: I don't understand your question. What are these non-standard orderings? Take any bijection between the two sets, it induces "non-standard" ordering on at least one of the sets and it becomes an isomorphism. Are you trying to separate the two sets by **any** order? That's vacuously false.

Comment: For eg, $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$ is a linearly ordered set, where $<$ is the standard ordering, i.e $ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: a< b \Longleftrightarrow b = a+c,$ for some $c\in \mathbb{Z^{nonneg}}$

Comment: What? Please read the question that you have posted again. Then read my answer, again.

Comment: My previous reply was to justify what I mean by "standard ordering". So, when you say $(\Bbb Q, <)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1], \lhd)$, how do you define $<$ and $\lhd$?

Comment: I know what is the definition of the standard order. I wanted to know what it had to do with the previous comment or the answer. I also don't see why you insist to ignore the information in my answer. The definition of both orders is standard.

Comment: You have hinted that $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1] $ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Q $ and I did acknowledge it in my reply. I might have wrongly perceived that the question requires one to define two different linear orderings on set $A,B$ where the orderings are not the standard ordering.

Comment: Well, in the risk of revealing too much... Can you find a subset of $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ which is isomorohic to the rationals with the standard order?